# How to mock exception branch using mock/pytest

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I have following code to test and I want to test the except branch:

```
def auto_commit(func):
    def _decorator(session, *args, **meta):
        try:
            session.begin()
            res = func(session, *args, **meta)
            session.commit()
            return res
        except Exception:
            session.rollback()
            raise

    return _decorator
```

And in test case module, I want to test it like this:

```
from xxx import get_session

@auto_commit
def _bad_func(session):
    raise ValueError('a random error')


def test_session_rollback(mocker):
    session = get_session()
    mocker.patch(session, 'rollback')

    try:
        _bad_func(session)
    except:
        pass

    assert session.rollback.assert_called_once()
```

Currently this does not work. How should write this mock properly? I can accept without calling `get_session` (i.e. `session = MagicMock()` etc etc).

BTW, The `mocker` is https://pypi.org/project/pytest-mock/

Answer (score 0):

Patch is useful to replace object in module / class.
Here you don't need to patch, just provide a mock object as argument.

```py
def test_session_rollback():
    session_mock = mock.MagicMock()
    try:
        _bad_func(session_mock)
    except Exception:
        pass
    session_mock.rollback.assert_called_once()
```